# How to load the WordPress themes correctly in my local host?

Tags: wordpress, css, virtualhost

I have a new customer that has send me a WordPress project. So to install the project it in my local machine, I have created a virtual host like the one below in my machine. So I can access like this `http://barraquete/index.php` to the content.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName barraquete

  SetEnv MYAPP_ENV dev

  DocumentRoot /home/tirengarfio/workspace/barraquete/archivos
  <Directory /home/tirengarfio/workspace/barraquete/archivos>
      # Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      #Order allow,deny
      #allow from all
      Require all granted
      <IfModule mod_mime.c>
          Addtype font/truetype .ttf
          AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css font/opentype font/truetype
      </IfModule>
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          Options -MultiViews

          RewriteEngine On
          #RewriteBase /path/to/app
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
      </IfModule>
      <IfModule mod_expires.c>
          ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
      ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
      ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
      ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I load the `index.php` I get the content of the page, but the `.css` files are not loaded..

These are the kind of URLs:

```
http://localhost:8888/barra-web/wp-content/themes/enfold/css/base.css?ver=1
```

So what should I do to get the themes correctly?

Comment: set the site url properly from backend->general config

Answer (score 1):

Reconfigure your localhost server to use port 80 not 8888, your virtual host is using port 80. Or in your wp_options table change your home_url and site_url to use port 8888. Whichever you want to use bot your server and WP have to point to the same port.